# Bootstrap jQuery Modal not loading on button click

Tags: javascript, jquery, ruby-on-rails, twitter-bootstrap, bootstrap-modal

I'm using Twitter Bootstrap loaded via CDN for my Rails 4 app, and when clicking on a button that should load a modal, nothing happens. If I try to trigger the modal via jQuery I get the error: Uncaught TypeError: undefined is not a function. Here's my code:

```
.container
.row
    .col-sm-12
        %h1 Manage Team
        .pull-right
            %a.btn.btn-success#addUserBtn{ data: { toggle: :modal, target: '#new_user' } }
                Add
```

Modal:

```
#new_user.modal.fade
.modal-dialog
    .modal-content
        .modal-header
            %button.close{ type: :button, 'data-dismiss' => 'modal', 'aria-hidden' => 'true' }
                &times;
            %h4.modal-title
                New Agency
        = form_for Agency.new( facilitator_id: current_user.id ) do |f|
            .modal-body
                .form-group
                    = f.label :name
                    = f.text_field :name, class: 'form-control'
                .form-group
                    = f.label :facilitator_id
                    = f.collection_select :facilitator_id, User.admin, :id, :name, {}, class: 'form-control'

            .modal-footer
                %button.btn.btn-default{ type: :button, 'data-dismiss' => 'modal' }
                    Close
                = f.submit 'Create', class: 'btn btn-primary'
```

jQuery:

```
$('#addUserBtn').on('click', function() {
    console.log('test');
    $('#new_user').modal('toggle');
});
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This was a bootstrap issue. When I loaded bootstrap using the gems rather than a CDN, everything worked correctly. Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 0):

you need to change #new_**agency**.modal.fade to #new_**user**.modal.fade in your modal code

Comment: Good catch. Changed that, but still no luck.